# compare two numerical variables and notify if there is a two points difference

Tags: php

I have two numerical variables which I want to compare and notify if there is more than 2 points difference (in php). How do I do that?

```
$totslopes
$slopes
```

Answer (score 1):

This goes beyond trivial.

To check if the difference between to numbers is greater than 2, you check if the difference between the two numbers is greater than two. That is all, you just do it:

```
if (abs($topslopes - $slopes) > 2) {
   // wat
}
```

Comment: But that is in case totslopes is greater than slopes. And the otherway around?